# How to serve static files on startup?

Tags: server, google-chrome, sudo, nodejs

I have a kiosk, which displays a website inside of chrome, on full-screen mode.

Website files, are static html templates, and they're stored in: `/home/kiosk/app` directory and I want to display them on startup.

I have two desktop files in `/home/kiosk/.config/autostart`. they both look like this (Chrome just points to different Exec path):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/kiosk/.config/autostart/serve.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Serve
```

Scripts:

- `chrome.sh` -> `google-chrome http://localhost:8080/`
- `serve.sh` -> `sudo static /home/kiosk/app #uses node-static package`

they both have NOPASSWD permission in `/etc/sudoers`

**The problem is:** website is not served.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, by using `gksudo` in desktop files, like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gksudo /home/kiosk/.config/autostart/serve.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Serve
```

I dont know why this worked though, if anyone knows, please tell.